# Counting number of images in folder (sort of)

Tags: javascript, html, loops

What I am trying to do is an image gallery in which you can navigate by arrows (left and right). There is x images in the image folder (for example let it be 8). Clicking the left arrow triggers the left() function:

```
function left() {
                number--; // number variable is 1 for default, it's used for changing images which are named slide1 slide2... so I can change it like that: "slide" + number
                document.getElementById("js_gallery_image").setAttribute("src", "img/" + "slide" + number + ".jpg"); //changes the number
```

and the right arrrow triggers the right() function which is the same but with number++ instead of number--.

And this was the code that I made at first but there is one more thing: when you go to the last image (8th one) clicking the right button should show the first image. I did it by adding an invisible img tag named #test, so I changed the right() function to that:

```
            function right() {
                number++;

                document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("src", "img/" + "slide" + number + ".jpg"); //changes the test image path to next slide.

                document.getElementById("test").onload = () => change(); // if number isn't greater than 8 image will load and change() function will change the image in gallery
                document.getElementById("test").onerror = () => {
                    number = 1;
                    change();
                }; // if number is greater than 8 it will throw an error so number will be changed to one and the change() function will be triggered.
            };
```

and that worked, but how to do it with the left function, so when the first image is displayed and you click the left arrow it will show you the last image? I tried to do that:

```
function left() {
                number--;

                document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("src", "img/" + "slide" + number + ".jpg");

                document.getElementById("test").onload = () => change();
                document.getElementById("test").onerror = () => {
                    let err = false;
                    do {
                        number++
                        document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("src", "img/" + "slide" + number + ".jpg");
                        document.getElementById("test").onerror = () => err = true;
                    } while (err == false) //it pluses 1 to number untill test image throws an error which should be thrown when the number is greater than 8
                };
```

And this didn't work, it gives me a result of an infinite loop. I trieed to do that using break statements and others but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks like, you have an issue with the loop and the fact that it is adding a listener, but is not waiting for the listener to do anything, causing the code to just loop and not wait for anything, and changing it again, not wait...

the fix for that could be to just make another loop inside of a loop and set the number to a variable to reduce having to download the same assets multiple times.

The code would look like this:

```
let maxImg = 0;
function findMax(){
    let currentMax = 1; //initially sets it to one because I presume you will have at least one image in the gallary
    let stoploop = false;
    let testImg = new Image();
    testImg.onload = function () {
        currentMax += 1;
        stoploop = true;
    }
    testImg.onerror = function () {
        maxImg = currentMax;
        stoploop = true;
    }
    testImg.setAttribute("src", "img/" + "slide" + (currentMax + 1) + ".jpg");
    function loop() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!stoploop) {
                loop();
            } else {
                if (maxImg < 1) {
                    testImg.setAttribute("src", "img/" + "slide" + (currentMax + 1) + ".jpg");
                    loop();
                }
            }
        }, 500);//done to not completely bog down the computer, may adjust if needbe 
    }
    loop();
}
```

so in practice, you would have to have your left function look like this:

```
function left() {
                number--;

                document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("src", "img/" + "slide" + number + ".jpg");

                document.getElementById("test").onload = () => change();
                document.getElementById("test").onerror = () => {
                    document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("src", "img/" + "slide" + maxImg + ".jpg");
                    number = maxImg;
                };
}
```

NOTE: With your current solution of testing through the client side you will have to have increased load time because you have to load all of the images, and that includes waiting for the images to be downloaded from the server one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with this

```js
let number = 0;
let last = 9999999;
const img = document.getElementById("test")
const prev = document.getElementById("prev");
const next = document.getElementById("next");

const changeImg = () => img.setAttribute("src", "img/" + "slide" + number + ".jpg");

img.onerror = () => { // should only trigger once at the end of the list
  last = number - 1;
  if (number<0) {
    console.log("no images found")
    return;
  }
  number = last;
  changeImg()
}
nav.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  tgt = e.target;
  dir = tgt.id === "prev" ? -1 : 1;
  number += dir
  if (number < 0 || number >= last) number = 0;
  prev.disabled=number===0;
  changeImg()
})
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <button class="btn" id="prev" disabled type="button">Prev</button>
  <img id="test" src="img/slide0.jpg">
  <button class="btn" id="next" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/diogocosta/5w042uL1/4/

HTML

```
<button id="prev-button" disabled onclick="prevImage()">Previous</button>
<button id="next-button" onclick="nextImage()">Next</button>
<img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/any" id="img-content">
```

JS

```
const images = [
  'https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals',
  'https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature',
  'https://placeimg.com/300/300/people',
  'https://placeimg.com/300/300/tech',
  'https://placeimg.com/300/300/sepia',  
]
const TOTAL_IMGS = 5
let currentImg = 1
const imgContent = document.getElementById('img-content')

function nextImage () {
  if (currentImg < TOTAL_IMGS) {
    currentImg++
    imgContent.setAttribute('src', images[currentImg-1])
  }
  updateButtonState()
}

function prevImage () {
  if (currentImg > 1) {
    currentImg--
    imgContent.setAttribute('src', images[currentImg-1])
  }
  updateButtonState()
}

// Enables and disables button
function updateButtonState() {
  const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-button')
  const prevButton = document.getElementById('prev-button')
    if (currentImg === 1) {
    nextButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
    prevButton.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  } else if (currentImg === TOTAL_IMGS) {
    nextButton.setAttribute('disabled', true)
    prevButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
  } else {
    nextButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
    prevButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: I forgot to add that I wanted to do it without defining the number of images so I can add more images to the website without changing the code. Thanks anyway and sorry for not typing it in the question.

Comment: The problem on your approach is that on the client side, you can't access a folder directly  to count the amount of images. There are two options for what you want to do: either get a list of images from the backend (so it always keep dynamic), or you manually add a thumbnail area with all the images, and keep the current image displayed big once you select a thumb (similar to ecommerces). This way you just need to count the amount of thumb images with a simple `querySelectorAll()` method.